# Magento 2 Customer CSV import Error 500

Tags: magento-2.1, error, import

I'm trying to import customers to a Magento 2 website. Data validation is OK (**File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button**), but when I click on import button, page gets stuck on please wait loader and I get error :

> POST
>   https://www.my-domain.com/administration/admin/import/start/key/8adc97…ad82c7953b3d1041f73b2365f835465e6552bba89c2b456/&form_key=5VWWozeXbFPTNSAr
>   500 (Internal Server Error) validation.min.js:6

I also tried to export / import existing customers (3) to be sure I did not have wrong data in my csv or too many customers.

Folders have the right permissions.

I'm using Magento 2.1.7 on a dedicated Linux server.

I can't find what could be wrong here, any idea ?

Comment: I'd check the apache error log file. Error 500 means that literally everything could have gone wrong - from an error in a PHP file to a timeout of your proxy, if you're using nginx for example. If your CSV file is very large, I'd assume it's something about memory_limit, post_max_size or upload_max_size

Comment: Yes, I was checking the logs right now. I have **mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackendModel() on null in /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Import/Customer.php:390, referer: https://www.my-domain.com/administration/admin/import/index/key/c3b34d750a8a8496c752b5abd2cae55bf803b8e450cb92f74dec07e3940cd2aa/**. I also have this error with the small file I exported and tried ti reimport without any changes, with only 3 customers..

Comment: I think customer attributes that have been added by you or an extension can cause this problem.

Comment: Indeed, I added 2 customer attributes, one following [link](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html) and one directly in database with phpmyadmin. The second one is causing the problem, I have to check what I did wrong there. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: I forgot to add the attribute in entity_attribute_id, problem soved ! Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to hear, no problem. You can write an answer and self-accept it to help other ppl with this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Followed this and resolved https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28115